# Trying to create a Like Button on model

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have been struggling with implementing a like button for a model for days now.I have a model that goes like this

```
class Feed(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='feeds')
    text=models.TextField(blank=False,max_length=500)
    user_concerns=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name="likes",blank=True)
@property
    def total_concerns(self):
        return self.user_concerns.count()
```

I am trying to make users to like a feed in the front end.So I have this view and url

```
#urls.py
urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^like/$', views.like, name='like'),]

#views.py
@require_POST
def like(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.user
        slug = request.POST.get('slug', None)
        feed = get_object_or_404(Feed, slug=slug)

        if feed.user_concerns.filter(id=user.id).exists():
            # user has already liked this company
            # remove like/user
            feed.user_concerns.remove(user)
            message = 'You disliked this'
        else:
            # add a new like for a company
            feed.user_concerns.add(user)
            message = 'You liked this'

    ctx = {'likes_count': feed.total_concerns, 'message': message}
    # use mimetype instead of content_type if django < 5
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(ctx), content_type='application/json')
```

and the template

```
<p>{{feed_detail.text|linebreaks}} </p>
          <p> {{feed_detail.total_concerns}} concern{{feed_detail.total_concerns|pluralize:'s'}}</p>
           <p> {{feed_detail.pub_date|naturaltime|capfirst}} </p>
                    <input type="button" id="like" name="{{feed_detail.slug}}" value="Like" />

<script>

$('#like').click(function(){

      $.ajax({

               type: "POST",
               url: "{% url 'like' %}",
               data: {'slug': '{{feed_detail.slug}}' , 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
               dataType: "json",
               success: function(response) {
                      alert(response.message);
                      alert('Company likes count is now ' + response.likes_count);
                },
                error: function(rs, e) {
                       alert(rs.responseText);
                }
          }); 
    })

</script>
```

Its not showing any error at all.Its showing the button but no action is carried out on click,Kindly help me because I am going nuts with this

Comment: Hit `Ctrl+Shift+J` on Chrome/Firefox and see if there are any errors. If not, click the button a few times and see if there are any errors now.

Comment: @xyres I have  Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.What does that mean,please?

Comment: Maybe you have not included jQuery

Comment: @navit .Pls how am i going to do that?.I saw this js answer on another post    and thats all they had

Comment: I'll explain it in an answer.

Comment: @Bolaji You'll need to include jQuery in your HTML. Paste this `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` in your HTML head.

Comment: @xyres That worked perfectly.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have not included jQuery.

First, in your settings.py define your static directory.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Create a static folder in your app folder. Place the jQuery js file in app_name/static/app_name/js. Then in your template:

```
<head>
{% load staticfiles %}    
<script src="{% static "app_name/js/bootstrap.min.js" %}"></script>   
</head>
```

Comment: Should the jQuery js file be everything within the <script> in the html above?

Comment: No, the file is jQuery itself. Download from https://jquery.com/download/